File names become distorted on hover
I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 on my desktop. I've just noticed that when I try to upload a file, when the Open File section pops up, and I try to hover over the files, the files turn fuzzy or blurry. They return to normal when I hover over something else of some other place,
What could be the cause of this issue? I never faced it when I was using 22.04.
Here's a screenshot of how the issue looks like:

